# Onde fica salvo os bancos de dados WebSql no Chrome?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, google-chrome, websql

Gostaria de saber qual é o diretório dos bancos de dados feitos em WebSql, ou seja, onde eu posso encontrar o arquivo do banco de dados.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No navegador cole: `chrome://version`.
Dentro do diretório exibido em: `Profile Path` ou `Caminho de perfil` existirá uma pasta chamada `databases`. Lá encontrará o que procura.

Comment: Obrigado, mas como eu posso deletar um banco de dados. Eu criei um banco de dados mas ele não aparece lá.

Comment: No próprio google chrome: F12 > Application.
No item Clear storage você consegue apagar os dados tanto do webSql como as outras categorias de storage

Comment: Deu Certo , muito obrgado